# Grepping from a text file list

Tags: shell, grep

I know I can find specific types of files and then grep them in one shot, i.e.

```
find . -type f -name "*.log" -exec grep -o "some-pattern" {} \;
```

But I need to do this in two steps. This is because the find operation is expensive (there are lots of files and subdirectories to search). I'd like to save down the file-list to a text file, and then repeatedly grep for different patterns on this precomputed set of files whenever I need to. The first part is easy:

```
find . -type f -name "*.log" > my-file-list.txt
```

Now I have a file that looks like this:

```
./logs/log1.log
./logs/log2.log
etc
```

What does the grep look like? I've tried a few combinations but can't get it right.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`xargs grep "your pattern" < my-file-list.txt`

Comment: That was an insanely fast response, and worked like a charm. I wish I could upvote this multiple times, it would've taken me much longer to even google it :)

Comment: You can choose it as the best answer.  :-)

Comment: It doesn't work so will if the file list contains spaces int he names though :(

Comment: If you have control over the source of the file, you can use `-print0` (for `find`) and the `-0` option for `xargs`.

Comment: or `-d"\n"` for `xargs`